# Codepen.io also jsfiddle stop's working with `localStorage access`

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Here is the log:

```
build.js:8325 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
```

Source code :

```
/**
 * LocalStorageMemory save and load js objects in localStorage.
 */
var localStorageMemory = {
  localStorage: window.localStorage,
  /**
   * save  Put the object into storage.
   * @example Usage : save("MyObjectKey", myObject )
   * @method save
   * @param {String} Name Name of localstorage key
   * @param {object} Value Any object we can store.
   * @return {false | object} What ever we are stored intro localStorage.
   */
  save: function(name, obj) {
    try {
      return localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Something wrong in LocalStorageMemory class , method save! -> ", e);
      return false;
    }
  },
  /**
   * Load saved object from storage. Retrieve the object from storage or
   * return false.
   * @example Usage : var giveMeMyObject = load("MyObjectKey")
   * @function load
   * @param {String} Name Name of localstorage key
   * @return {false | object} What ever we are stored intro localStorage.
   */
  load: function(name) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(name) === "undefined" || localStorage.getItem(name) == null || localStorage.getItem(name) === "") {
      console.warn("LocalStorageMemory method load return's: ", localStorage.getItem(name));
      return false;
    } else {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
    }
  }
}



/**********CREATE INSTANCE***********/

var saveAnyDataObj = {
  name: "wins",
  numberOfWins: c++
};

localStorageMemory.save("MyObject1", saveAnyDataObj);



var getMyMemory = localStorageMemory.load("MyObject1");
console.log("MyObject1 = ", getMyMemory);

var c = 0;

setInterval(function() {

var saveAnyDataObj = {
  name: "wins",
  numberOfWins: c++
};

localStorageMemory.save("MyObject1", saveAnyDataObj);

getMyMemory = localStorageMemory.load("MyObject1");

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getMyMemory.numberOfWins;
}, 1000);
```

Try it :

https://codepen.io/zlatnaspirala/pen/NRYKzJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of many sandbox values for `iframe`s: `allow-same-origin`. There is no way you can defeat it.

My guess why JS Fiddle and Codepen don't allow it since one script could put some form of secrets into localstorage and another (potentially malicious) script could read those as they are on the same origin.

You can read why Stack Exchange disallows it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345386/23528

Comment: I guess with `pro account` is allowed. ;)

Comment: I quick fix lib with try and catch, with my lucky localStorage usage have only access from one custom function...